# Django MariaDB-Galera Perfermance on K8s

Tags: django, kubernetes, mariadb, galera

I'm currently trying to find a good database solution for my app that runs on K8s at a "massive scale". So I started to experiment with MariaDB Galera without having any further experiences with it. I noticed that the write performance is quite slow. On a single instance MariaDB I can write 500 rows each with 7 field in about 2,75 Seconds (Single Table). Using Galera I need about 12-15 seconds for the same insert. Sometimes even more than 20 sec. Why that?

Im running on High-End Hardware with NVMe drives, 10 Gbit Network and Epyc CPUs. Overhead should be small as everything run in Containers. Is this "issue" just the nature of Galera or is my config just faulty?! please see here: https://pastebin.com/mvb3Ndww

I already experimented with `query_cache_type` and `query_cache_size` but without any real success so far ...

My CSI is openebs-hostpath for maximum performance through a locally attached disk for each container/Pod.

My Database settings at settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET innodb_strict_mode=1',
            'connect_timeout': 30,
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
        'NAME': env.str('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': env.str('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env.str('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env.str('MYSQL_HOST'),
        'PORT': env.str('MYSQL_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the nature of the data you are writing and do you have indexes that may slow you down? how many threads/connections are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington not sure what you mean by "nature of the data you are writing" And I dont know if I have any indexes that might slow the perfomance, DB noob here

Comment: How much RAM?..

Comment: Between 8-16GB RAM, 4-8 CPUs, depends on current flavour we use for our workers

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` one row at a time is slow.  These are faster:

- Batched insert (many rows in a single `INSERT`).  Recommend 100 to 1000 rows at a time.
- `LOAD DATA INFILE`

The Query Cache slows down inserts.  Anyway, it is not allowed on Galera.

How far apart (in milliseconds) are the nodes?

These are terribly high, go back to the defaults:

```
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Some places specify utf8, some specify utf8mb4.  The latter is preferred.  The inconsistency may be causing some performance lag.

Comment: Well these are the defaults provided by the bitnami team, thats where I got this my.cnf from What do you think is a good value to go for 128-256MB ? With my nodes I've got 0.4 ms in between ping replies

Comment: @sunwave121 - 1% of RAM is a compromise between large enough to be useful (sometimes) and small enough to be safe.  The problem is that lots of 2G allocations could happen at the same time, thereby causing swapping, which causes a big slowdown.

Comment: @sunwave121 - I can't explain the slowness, but suggest that batching will help significantly.